# How to create a Point Cloud from multiple images in Open3D?

Tags: python, opencv, open3d

My goal is to create a Point Cloud of an object using multiple images taken from different angles (circular pattern around it) using Open3D in Python. So far I have successfully obtained the Point Cloud of a single image, but I haven't figured out how to "merge" the whole dataset of images to create a global Point Cloud.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import glob
import sys
import open3d as o3d

# Downsample function
def downsample_image(image, reduce_factor): 
        for i in range(0, reduce_factor):
                # Validar si la imagen está a color o escala de grises
                if len(image.shape) > 2:
                        row,col = image.shape[:2]
                else:
                        row,col = image.shape
                img = cv2.pyrDown(image, dstsize= (col // 2, row // 2))
        return image

# Neural Network
path_model = 'models/'
model_name = 'model-f6b98070.onnx'; # MiDas v2.1 Large
model = cv2.dnn.readNet(path_model + model_name)

# Reading and processing images
images = glob.glob('/path-to-images/*.jpg')
pcds = []
count = 1
for image in images:
        img = cv2.imread(image)
        img = downsample_image(img, 3)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        imgHeight, imgWidth, channels = img.shape
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255., (384,384), (123.675, 116.28, 103.53), True, False)
        model.setInput(blob)
        output = model.forward()
        output = output[0,:,:]
        output = cv2.resize(output, (imgWidth, imgHeight))
        output = cv2.normalize(output, None, 0, 1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
        cv2.imwrite('images/%s-colorImg.jpg' % count, img)
        cv2.imwrite('images/%s-depthImg.jpg' % count, output)
        color_raw = o3d.io.read_image('images/%s-colorImg.jpg' % count)
        depth_raw = o3d.io.read_image('images/%s-depthImg.jpg' % count)
        rgbd_image = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(color_raw, depth_raw)
        cv_file = cv2.FileStorage()
        cv_file.open('cameraIntrinsic.xml', cv2.FileStorage_READ)
        camera_intrinsic = cv_file.getNode('intrinsic').mat()
        camera_intrinsic_o3d = o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(width=2592, height=1944, fx=camera_intrinsic[0][0], fy=camera_intrinsic[1][1], cx=camera_intrinsic[0][2], cy=camera_intrinsic[1][2])
        pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(rgbd_image, camera_intrinsic_o3d)    
        pcd.transform([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0 ,0], [0, 0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])    
        pcds.append(pcd)
        o3d.io.write_point_cloud("pointclouds/pointCloud%s.ply" %count, pcd)
        count += 1
```

With this code a Point Cloud for every image is created, but all of them are aproximately in the same plane, which make sense since I haven't introduced any position argument for the camera. I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pk77M4KBg2Q) where a camera trajectory is used to place each Point Cloud in its "real world" coordinates but it didn't specify how to get that camera trajectory and I've been surfing the web for days trying to figure it out but there is not much material on this.

Here are 3 consecutive images from my data set:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p9d6v9k5pvasgp3/AAB2k1YXJWZKFp0EnDIkq6C5a?dl=0

And here is my cameraIntrinsic file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mcccqh63k3h74xv/cameraIntrinsic.xml?dl=0

Does anyone know how to get the camera trajectory? Can I extract that from the extrinsic parameters of a camera with OpenCV?